# Is CAST from integer to text collation specific?

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, collation

If I use cast an `integer` to a string type like `cast(phone as text)`, is there a theoretical chance that the produced string could differ depending on the collation of the database?

In other words, could the result depend on the an added `COLLATE` clause  (especially for integers):

```
select cast(q as text) COLLATE "somecollation";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `COLLATION` has no bearing on the cast from `int` to `text` whatsoever. The resulting *value* is always the same.

The `COLLATION` does affect how the same `text` value is later sorted or treated in regular expressions, though. If you attach a `COLLATE` clause to the cast (or *any* expression returning a string type), the collation sticks to the value until an assignment or the next expression may change it.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)

> The collation feature allows specifying the sort order and character classification behavior of data per-column, or even per-operation [...]